# Wordpress loop only gets attached media the first time in the loop. Why?

Tags: php, loops, wordpress

I have built a "slider" for testimonials for a Wordpress website. The testimonials are built as a custom post type. I am looping through and grabbing certain pieces of information like the_excerpt() and i'm also grabbing the attached media; which is an audio file of the testimonial. For some reason that I can't figure out, this loop gets the attached media only for the first post; the rest are all blank even though they do have the same type audio file uploaded in the exact same way. Please help! They get a class of even*/odd* for jQuery and CSS purposes.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'Testimonials', 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'orderby' => 'ASC' ) );
            $counter = 1;
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                echo '<div id="testimonialPost'; echo $counter; echo '" class="'; echo (($counter % 2) == 1) ? "Odd" : "Even"; echo $counter; echo (($counter % 2) == 1) ? " Odd" : " Even";  echo '">';
                    echo '<div class="testimonialCopy volkorn blue">';
                        the_excerpt();
                        echo '<a class="audioTestimonial sourceSansPro bold gray" href="/testimonials">Click to hear more from our clients</a>';
                    echo '</div><!--.testimonialCopy-->';
                    echo '<div class="testimonialInformation">';
                        echo '<div class="featuredImage">';
                            the_post_thumbnail();
                        echo '</div><!--.featuredImage-->';
                        echo '<div class="nameAndStuff"><h2 class="name sourceSansPro blue">';
                            echo get_the_title();
                        echo '</h2><!--.name-->';
                        echo '<h2 class="nativeLanguage sourceSansPro blue">';
                            echo extra_information_get_meta( 'extra_information_extra_information_native_language' );
                        echo '</h2><!--.nativeLanguage-->';
                        echo '<a>Hear my audio testimonial</a>';
                        echo '</div><!--.nameAndStuff-->';
                    echo '</div><!--.testimonialInformation-->';
                echo '</div><!--.testimonialPost-->';
                $audio_attachments = get_posts( array(
                        'post_parent' => $loop->the_post,
                        'post_type' => 'attachment',
                        'post_mime_type' => 'audio'
                    ) );
                    $audio_attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $audio_attachments->ID );
                    $audioAttr = array(
                        'src'      => $audio_attachment_url,
                        'loop'     => $loop,
                        'autoplay' => '',
                        'preload' => 'none'
                    );
                    echo '<div class="packagePop audioTestimonialPop" style="display:none;"><div class="closeBtn"></div>'. wp_audio_shortcode( $audioAttr ).'</div>';
                $counter += 1;
endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here with 'loop' => $loop, ?? What does it do?

`$audioAttr = array(
                        'src'      => $audio_attachment_url,
                        'loop'     => $loop,`

Comment: woops, that should be 'loop' => '', - it was something i was just throwing out there and hoping would stick

Comment: Try changing this

                       'post_parent' => $loop->the_post,

to this

                       'post_parent' => $loop->ID

Comment: that didn't give me any different result, oddly